# Why does MemoryTest appear error in pass 2?

Tags: motherboard, memtest86+

I have 4 slots RAM and 3 RAMs 2GB. Individually,I've tested :

- 1st slot with 1st RAM
- 2nd slot with 2nd RAM
- 3rd slot with 3rd RAM
- 1st slot with each RAMs
- Two RAMs together.

  1. All pass 1 are fine, but when I tested 1st RAM in 2nd slot and 2nd RAM in 3rd slot together, pass 1 was ok but pass 2 show me some errors.
  2. When I tested my 2nd RAM in 1st slot have problem like Bios can't load.

So what is my problem and how can I solve it?

```
Base Board Information
    Manufacturer: MSI
    Product Name: B75MA-P45 (MS-7798)
    Version: 1.0
    Serial Number: To be filled by O.E.M.
    Asset Tag: To be filled by O.E.M.
    Features:
        Board is a hosting board
        Board is replaceable
    Location In Chassis: To be filled by O.E.M.
    Chassis Handle: 0x0003
    Type: Motherboard
    Contained Object Handles: 0
```

---

#### *If I can provide more information, please don't hesitate let me know!*

Comment: @Ramhound sadly i can't find it in website. They only give me about RAM architecture.

Comment: The manual is [here](http://msi.com/product/motherboard/support/B75MA-P45.html#down-manual)

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks but It only has  RAM architecture about 2 RAMs or 4 RAMs . page 16

Comment: *"It only has RAM architecture about 2 RAMs or 4 RAMs"* -- If you want the memory to operate in dual-channel mode, you must install exactly two or four (i.e. 2xN) *matching* memory modules in the proper slots.  Any other module configuration will operate in single-channel mode.  IOW three modules cannot operate in dual-channel (regardless if they are matching or not), only single-channel mode is possible.

Comment: Describe in detail these three memory modules that you are trying to use.